# Recording audio interrupted by call

Tags: android, audio-recording, phone-call, audiorecord

This app needs to analyze the audio during a phone call, for that I'm using

```
MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC
```

in some phones the code works fine, but in other phones the AudioRecord stops during the phone call and when the call finish the AudioRecord start to work again.

**Do you know why? I want to understand if this is because the phones hardware or android version!**

Comment: Which ones does it work on and which ones doesn't it? Look for the common denominator.

Comment: @CaptJak 
Works on: Phone: Blu - Android: 4.4.2 - Kernel: 3.4.67

Doesn't work: Phone: Samsung - Android: 4.0.4 - Kernel: 3.0.8, Phone: Huawei - Android: 4.1.1 - Kernel: 3.4.0, Phone: Blu - Android: 4.4.4 - Kernel: 3.10.28

Comment: Are you wrapping your call to the microphone within an IntentService? If not, that might be your problem right there. Phones reclaim resources at different rates. Even the same exact phone model could work one time, but not work the next time around, depending on how much resources it currently has available to it.